# Can't access server_block running on different port than 80 using Nginx

Tags: nginx, server

I am trying to run nginx on company server on port other than 80. Since 80 is reserved, I chose port 8082.
I need to run it without domain so I could access it using only IP address and port number. Something like this: `serverip:8082`.

I got it working on my own VPS by configuring server block like this. When i try the same settings on company server, it won't work.

```
server {
        listen 8082;
        listen [::]:8082;
        ...
}
```

**Some more information**

- Server is running on Ubuntu 16.04
- I'm not using server_name in my server block.
- Server block is linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.
- I am using UFW and I have 8082 enabled (ufw is the only firewall enabled on server)
- I see no errors in nginx error log.
- I tried restarting nginx
- I tried editing default server_block to listen on port 8082. Still nothing.
- I unlinked default server_block when trying my own.
- When I run **sudo lsof -i TCP:8082** I get result like this:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   19668     root    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19668     root    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19771 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19771 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19772 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19772 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19773 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19773 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19774 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19774 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19775 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19775 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19776 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19776 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19777 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19777 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19778 www-data    6u  IPv4 20068810      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
nginx   19778 www-data    7u  IPv6 20068811      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
```

- My **entire server_block**

```
server {
        listen 8082;
        listen [::]:8082;
        index index.php;
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        error_log /home/myuser/projects/synt_logs/synt.log;
        access_log /home/myuser/projects/synt_logs/synt.access.log;
        root /home/myuser/projects/synt/public;

        location /{
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

When I try to connect to `serverip:8082` It just loads then I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT.

Can you help me identify the problem I am facing? I am trying to figure this out since yesterday with no success. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `listen 8082 default_server; server_name anythingrandom;` ? It looks like nginx binds to all network interfaces - so it is either these settings or the firewall.

Comment: I tried as you said, but the problem persists. Problem persists even if I turn firewall off.

Comment: Are you sure that nginX does not emit errors, that error log has proper permissions, there are no related messages in the system logs ? Can you try `curl http://127.0.0.1:8082` on the VPS itself ?

Comment: If I do the ```curl http://127.0.0.1:8082```I can see my website in the output!


If I check systemlogs using ```dmesg```, I can see some ```[UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=address SRC=10.0.0.17 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=43309 PROTO=2 ```


However I disabled ufw altogether now so it's maybe from earlier?


In Nginx logs I see only logs like this: ```signal process started```

Comment: Did you simply disabled the UFW service from starting in the future, or you have also stopped/killed the running UFW service?

Comment: Stopped. If i run ```ufw status``` I get "Status: inactive"

Comment: Maybe there is another firewall in front of your VPS, provided by your cloud ?

Comment: I will have to ask, but I can assume that is the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If the same config works on port 80 but not on 8082 - then this is definitely a firewall issue.

Comment: I can't say if it works on port 80, because the port is occupied and nginx won't even start.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem is that there was another layer of firewall outside of VPS which blocked the port 8082.
By contacting administrator, he fixed the problem for me and it is now working.